# stroll, strol functions not giving correct output for long_min

Tags: c++, strtol, strtoull

For the following code

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   bitset<64>b(numeric_limits<long>::min());
   string s=b.to_string();
   char *ptr=new char [s.size()+1];
   strcpy(ptr,s.c_str());
   long l1=strtol(ptr,NULL,2);
   cout<<"l1= "<<l1<<endl;
  long l2=strtoul(ptr,NULL,2);
   cout<<"l2= "<<l2<<endl;
   cout<<strtoul(ptr,NULL,2)<<endl;
}
```

The output is

```
l1= 9223372036854775807
l2= -9223372036854775808
9223372036854775808
```

Why is `l1` not `long_min` and why is `l2`? I've read that the string can contain `+`/`-` sign in the beginning for ato*,strto* functions. But negative numbers in binary don't have any `-` sign in 2's complement that computer uses. I'm confused.

Comment: errno is supposed to be set to ERANGE, don't forget to check it.  [And this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `unsigned long int` value

```
9223372036854775808
```

outputted by this statement

```
cout<<strtoul(ptr,NULL,2)<<endl;
```

can not be represented in an object of the type `signed long int`.

In this statement

```
long l1=strtol(ptr,NULL,2);
```

as the value is not representable in the type `signed long int` the function `strtol` returns `LONG_MAX` (because there is no minus sign in the string).  And this value is outputted by this statement

```
cout<<"l1= "<<l1<<endl;
```

From the C Standard (7.22.1.4 The strtol, strtoll, strtoul, and strtoull functions)

> 8 The strtol, strtoll, strtoul, and strtoull functions return the
>   converted value, if any. If no conversion could be performed, zero is
>   returned. **If the correct value is outside the range of representable
>   values, LONG_MIN, LONG_MAX, LLONG_MIN, LLONG_MAX, ULONG_MAX, or
>   ULLONG_MAX is returned** (according to the return type and sign of the
>   value, if any), and the value of the macro ERANGE is stored in errno.

However the value is representable as an `unsigned long int`. So this call of the function `strtoul` returns the correct value

```
long l2=strtoul(ptr,NULL,2);
```

but the value is assigned to an object of the type `signed long int`. So its most significant bit is interpreted as the sign bit and the next statement

```
cout<<"l2= "<<l2<<endl;
```

outputs the value `LONG_MIN`.

Answer (score 1):

You get an `ERANGE` error for supplying a positive value larger than what a `long` can hold. To make it work with `strtol` you need to add a `-`:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   std::bitset<64> b(std::numeric_limits<long>::min());

   std::string s = "-" + b.to_string();

   long l1=strtol(s.c_str(), NULL, 2);
   std::cout << "l1= " << l1 << '\n';
}
```

Possible output:

```
l1= -9223372036854775808
```

Comment: ptr in my example is `LONG_MIN` which a long can hold. Why is the sign necessary for base 2? Have I supplied `LONG_MAX+1` or `LONG_MIN` to strtol?

Comment: `strtol` requires a `-` for negative values, otherwise it'll be interpreted as a positive value. The base doesn't matter.